# Returning a .Net Dictionary with parameterized types. C++/CLI

Tags: generics, dictionary, c++-cli

I am having some disagreements with the VS2012 IDE, I have recently made a move from C# to C++/CLI and I may barely know it, but everything has been going smoothly except this one small bump.  I under stand parameterized types very well, I just can't seem to figure out how to return something that has a parameterized type.  I looked it all up on multiple web sites, and I found out there are two ways to do this: a `generic` and a `template`

This is how I would do it in C#: `public static Dictionary<TKey, TVal> MakeDictionary<TKey, TVal>(List<TKey> Keys, List<TVal> Values){/*code*/}` and in C++/CLI I tried:

```
generic<typename TKey, typename TVal> static Dictionary<TKey, TVal> ^MakeDictionary<TKey, TVal>(List<TKey> ^Keys, List<TVal> ^Values){/*code*/}
```

and

```
template<typename TKey, typename TVal> static Dictionary<TKey, TVal> ^MakeDictionary<TKey, TVal>(List<TKey> ^Keys, List<TVal> ^Values){/*code*/}
```

amongst other things, always getting the same problem with the compiler not recognizing TKey and TVal.

My question: how do I specify the type parameters, and what is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are improperly combining C# and C++/CLI syntax that specifies the generic type parameters.  In C# it is done by putting them in `<brackets>` after the method name.  In C++/CLI it is done by putting them in the `generic<>` clause.  So just drop the ones after the method name:

```
generic<typename TKey, typename TVal> 
static Dictionary<TKey, TVal>^  MakeDictionary(List<TKey>^ Keys, List<TVal>^ Values) {}
```